# Custom error message not showing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm having a AngularJS auto complete input component in my app. I want to show a custom error message according to a condition in my controller. This is what I tried.

This is my controller.

```
ctrl.searchAddresses = function(searchAddresses) {
return addressService.searchAddresses(searchAddresses)
  .then((response) => { 

    if(response.length == 0) {
      $scope.addressNotMatch = true;

    }

    residentForm.serviceAddress.$setValidity('validationError', true);
    return response;

  }, (error) => { 
    $scope.resident.serviceAddress = '';
})}
```

In here what I'm doing is I'm calling to an API through a service where it returns address list. If the length of address equals to zero I want to show an error message in my view as 'No addresses found'.

This is the auto complete component in my view

```
        <md-autocomplete class="cl-autocomplete" lex md-require-match md-selected-item="resident.serviceAddress" md-input-name="serviceAddress" md-search-text="addressSearchText" placeholder="Service Address *" md-items="address in $residentHomeController.searchAddresses(addressSearchText)"
            md-item-text="address" md-selected-item-change="$residentHomeController.selectedAddress(resident.serviceAddress)" ng-required="true" md-input-minlength="1" md-delay="1000">
            <md-item-template>
                {{address}}
            </md-item-template>
            <div ng-messages="residentForm.serviceAddress.$error" ng-if="residentForm.serviceAddress.$touched">
                <div ng-message="required">Address is required</div>
            </div>
            <div ng-messages="residentForm.serviceAddress.$error" ng-if="addressNotMatch">
                <div ng-message="validationError">No match found</div>
            </div>
        </md-autocomplete>
```

No errors are shown. Could someone please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @sajeetharan please help

Comment: I guess ng-messages directive takes care of visibility criteria. Can you please try removing the ng-if ?

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure Tried that too. Still it's not working

Comment: I guess something is wrong with the ng-message parameter. In your code please check what value you are getting in residentForm.serviceAddress.$error. I believe there is no field with name validationError.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: Rakesh Burbure I'm referring 'validationError' in controller.

Comment: Yes, I know, but have you checked what data you are getting in residentForm.serviceAddress.$error?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has an issue like this , you can simple you build in md-not-found property like this

```
   <md-not-found>
    No matches found.
  </md-not-found>
```